# Can "universal wifi adapters" be connected to a switch instead of a end device?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge, wireless-bridge

I have been looking at "universal wifi adapters" (ethernet in/wifi out, looks like ethernet from the client side but speaks wifi) like the netgear wnce2001 for bridging the ethernet from a switch to another room via wifi. The product specs of those devices only talk about devices like video game consoles and TVs, but not about switches.

Would they work with switches or are they hardwired to talk to only one device?
What else could I use to connect my switch wireless to my wifi router, apart from "powerline" stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WiFi adapter like the Netgear WNCE2001 is also called an *access point* operating in client mode.  Typically the AP can only support one client device on the wired end, so a switch cannot be connected.

A wireless router (or an AP with routing features) operating in wireless bridge mode will provide the functionality you're asking for. You may have to use alternate firmware like DD-WRT if the stock firmware doesn't offer that mode.  See a similar question/answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/342333/airlink101-ap431w-access-point-only-bridging-first-mac-seen/342384#342384)

Comment: You're right, the WNCE2001 doesn't seem to be a real bridge. There are Linksys/Cisco products that'll do the trick, look for WET200 or WET610N

Comment: OK. I have an older router somewhere maybe it can be put into bridge mode. Need to check for model...

Answer (score 2):

the WNCE2001 DOES indeed act like a bridge as I have it connected to a 24 port switch (via WIFI) Works like a charm.

It does work, just not stated officially anywhere

Answer (score 1):

If this device is a wireless bridge, you can connect whatever device you like to it, even a switch (and other devices to the switch). If you need vlan-tagging or multicast you *may* run into some problems, but most likely you don't need those features at home (exception: IPTV).

Comment: None of those features are needed. The switch only serves a PC, a couple of old SPARCstations and a printer...