# Two PCs through one WiFi bridge, cannot be on simultaneously

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I recently purchased a TP-link WiFi extender, which I mostly use as a WiFi bridge for the wired devices in my bedroom since the other solutions I tried (such as homeplugs) simply weren't appropriate for this house.

I have one Desktop PC for working on, and one HTPC hooked up to my TV. This is done using an 8-port ethernet switch. It works wonderfully, my internet connection is reliable and fast, I can stream Plex down to the living room from the Desktop.

However, something strange happens as soon as I try to have both the Desktop and the HTPC switched on together, (which I sometimes need since I use the Desktop as a beefier machine for streaming Steam games to the TV).

If I have the Desktop on, and switch the HTPC on, the internet connection is completely lost. All sorts of issues, from the Default Gateway being unavailable to the DNS not responding. As soon as I switch the HTPC off again, the internet is back on the Desktop.

This is the first time I tried it, but yesterday I switched the HTPC on *first* and had no issues.

I have tried playing around with the DHCP settings on the TP Link device, manually setting the DNS servers (standard Virgin Media servers:  to use, telling it to use the router as the default gateway... But this doesn't seem to matter.

The router I am using is a Virgin Media Superhub, which actually seems to set its own IP as the DNS server for devices to use...

Any ideas what is happening? There doesn't seem to be any IP Clash between the PCs, which is the only thing my limited Networking knowledge could think of.

Could it be that the extender is acting as its own DHCP? Maybe that is messing with the router?

Comment: I don't have the extender you mention, but if it is offering dhcp services turn that option off.  Only the main router should provided dhcp for the entire network.  Also check the HTPC settings and make sure you didn't set a static local ip, or if you have to set it make just outside the main routers dhcp range.

Comment: I tried turning DHCP off, and then neither PC could get at the DHCP server... just made it worse.

Comment: It sounds like your creating a separate subnet for the devices connecting to the extender, you want only one subnet.

Comment: *"Any ideas what is happening?"* -- We're not there like you are, so you are the one that has to tell us ***what*** is happening.  For starters, you should be looking at the network interfaces of each host (i.e..the desktop and HTPC) (and at the router through its web page) under each situation.  What are their IP addresses? can you `ping` anything?  Does reacquiring the IP address help?  Worst case scenario is that you're in this situation: http://superuser.com/questions/342333/airlink101-ap431w-access-point-only-bridging-first-mac-seen/342384#342384

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the help, but it seemed not to be a networking issue at all... it was something weirder. I found that the extender stopped working even if I had the HTPC's Ethernet disconnected and WiFi disabled. So it was nothing to do with the network. I moved the extender to the other side of the room, and ran an Ethernet cable around the wall, and now it works perfectly.